# emacs DELETE/C-h confusion on OS X

Tags: macos, emacs

Going through the tutorial on emacs, I got stuck on the deleting part, because by default DELETE key sends me to help. I've tried adding a few popular commands to the .emacs file such as `(normal-erase-is-backspace-mode 1)`. So with that in my .emacs file, I hit `C-h` and get the screen that says `This buffer is for notes you don't want to save...`, then hit `t` and it just enters the letter into this "buffer". DELETE does what it's supposed to do now, though. When running `emacs -q` instead, I end up at the same "buffer" screen, except when I hit `t` it actually takes me to the tutorial, but the problem is of course that DELETE does not delete. Any solutions to this? I'm on a MacBook with OS X 10.9.4, using the Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the Emacs manual, node [`DEL Does Not Delete`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/DEL-Does-Not-Delete.html#DEL-Does-Not-Delete).  Just customize option `normal-erase-is-backspace`.  Or use `M-x normal-erase-is-backspace-mode` to toggle the value.

Hmm, but I see now that you have added that you tried this.  I do not understand what you mean by "notepad", so I do not understand that part.

Try this also, at a command prompt (assuming you are on GNU/Linux or similar):

```
stty erase ^H
```

And see various writeups on the web about `stty erase`.  (IOW, google `stty erase`.)

When you say DELETE, I'm guessing (hoping) that you mean the key labeled `Backspace` and not the key labeled `Delete`.  What does `C-h k` tell you when you use it and then hit each of these keys?

- the key labeled `Backspace`
- `C-h`, that is, press and hold `Control` then hit `h`
- the key labeled `Delete`

(And just which keys are you using to get the behavior that does not work?)

Comment: by DELETE, I do mean the key labeled exactly as that, I don't have Backspace, I'm using a Mac. And yes, the `(normal-erase-is-backspace-mode 1)` command I got from the page you linked. So with that in my .emacs file, I hit `C-h` and get the part I call "notepad", which says "This buffer is for notes you don't want to save...", then hit `t` and it just enters the letter into this buffer/"notepad". When running `emacs -q` instead, I end up at the same screen, except when I hit `t` it actually takes me to the tutorial. Customization suggestions is what I was hoping for.

Comment: and having done `stty erase ^H`, I can't surpass the buffer whether I run `emacs` or `emacs -q`. I can get rid of all the customizations and carry on, maneuvering around delete with some kind of `M-b` + `C-d` combos, but this is so odd.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm having a hard time following you (I don't know what you mean by "surpass the buffer" etc.). Hopefully someone else will be able to help more. FWIW: the "notepad" is buffer `*scratch*`. I have no idea why `C-h` just takes you to that buffer (and yes, in that buffer, `t` self-inserts). Try `M-x describe-key RET C-h` to see what command `C-h` is bound to. (Normally you would use `C-h k` to do that...) It sounds like you have something in your init file that is messing things up.  Try bisecting it (by commenting out 1/, 3/4...) to find what the culprit is.